# Is it Possible to Subscribe to Changes to Other Users' Private CloudKit Database?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am working on a CloudKit based app that will rely heavily on private user databases.

The goal I have now is to have multiple users that can "subscribe" to each other. Once they do that, their device registers for record creation notifications from another users' private database. This also wouldn't necessarily require the ability to read content in another users' private database.

Is this possible, and if so, what specific API calls would I need to get the private database of another user so that I can subscribe to it?

Comment: Thankfully no. It would defeat the purpose of it being *private*. Look into CloudKit's shared database features.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I would like to respect the content being private, but only know when the private database is updated. I'll check out the shared database.

Comment: @rmaddy what I am going for is to ultimately have content in a database unique to each user (which is why I mention the private database), but still let others users read from it with the permission of the database owner. How can this be done? Also, to my understand, the shared database is just a read only controlled access to one's private database. Is that correct?

Comment: Read about it in the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987).